# could we separated f(A) and f(B)by disjoint open sets in Y ?

Tags: general-topology

If f is continuous and bijection function of Hausdorff space X into Hausdorff space Y, and A,B are disjoint closed sets can not be separated by disjoint open sets in X. f(A) and f(B) are disjoint closed sets in Y.Could we separated f(A) and f(B)by disjoint open sets in Y ? Thanks.

Comment: I think no, but I cann't prove that.

Comment: If $U$ and $V$ separated $f(A)$ and $f(B)$, we could find disjoint open sets separating $A$ and $B$. You should be able to find these sets using elementary properties, Hausdorff isn't important here.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the conditions you give will have no effect on whether the claim is true. I won't spoil it, but I will give you a hint.

Suppose $X,Y$ are topological spaces, $f:X\to Y$ continuous, $A,B\subseteq X.$ Now, suppose that $U,V$ are disjoint open subsets of $Y$ such that $f(A)\subseteq U$ and $f(B)\subseteq V.$ What can you say about $f^{-1}(U):=\{x\in X:f(x)\in U\}$ and $f^{-1}(V):=\{x\in X:f(x)\in V\},$ given these hypotheses?

Comment: It is clear, thanks

Comment: So, we have a contradiction since A and B can't be separated. Thus f(A) and f(B) also can't be separated.is it right?

Comment: That's correct: and bijectivity, Hausdorffness, and closedness were irrelevant, so we actually have a fairly general result, here.